# error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int test::hotplug_callback(libusb_context*, libusb_device*, libusb_hotplug_event, void*)’

Tags: c++, libusb

I adapted the libusb hotplug example from

`* libusb example program for hotplug API
 * Copyright © 2012-2013 Nathan Hjelm <hjelmn@mac.com>`

(code below) as a test and put it in a class as I have the same issue with my real program. 
I know that if I put static in front of the two callbacks that it functions but I don't want them to be static. I want to access my instance variables from the callbacks. The idea is that the user plugs in a usb device let's call it usbXYZ. From the callback I instantiate class usbXYZ and put in an std::map - user removes it and I remove it from the map. The class that contains the std::map with the objects in it has a 'higher level' method to write to the devices.

How do I make the callback functions work none static please? If possible do explain it a little bit because I don't understand it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

#include "libusb-1.0/libusb.h"

class test{
public:
    test() {
        okGo();
    }

private:
    int done = 0;
    libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;

    int LIBUSB_CALL hotplug_callback(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device *dev, libusb_hotplug_event event, void *user_data)
    {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int rc;

        (void)ctx;
        (void)dev;
        (void)event;
        (void)user_data;

        rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error getting device descriptor\n");
        }

        printf ("Device attached: %04x:%04x\n", desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct);

        if (handle) {
            libusb_close (handle);
            handle = NULL;
        }

        rc = libusb_open (dev, &handle);
        if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error opening device\n");
        }

        done++;

        return 0;
    }

    int LIBUSB_CALL hotplug_callback_detach(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device *dev, libusb_hotplug_event event, void *user_data)
    {
        (void)ctx;
        (void)dev;
        (void)event;
        (void)user_data;

        printf ("Device detached\n");

        if (handle) {
            libusb_close (handle);
            handle = NULL;
        }

        done++;

        return 0;
    }

    int okGo(){
        libusb_hotplug_callback_handle hp[2];
        int product_id, vendor_id, class_id;
        int rc;

        vendor_id  = LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY;
        product_id = LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY;
        class_id   = LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY;

        rc = libusb_init (NULL);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            printf("failed to initialise libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (!libusb_has_capability (LIBUSB_CAP_HAS_HOTPLUG)) {
            printf ("Hotplug capabilites are not supported on this platform\n");
            libusb_exit (NULL);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback (NULL, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE, vendor_id,
                                               product_id, class_id, hotplug_callback, NULL, &hp[0]);
        if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error registering callback 0\n");
            libusb_exit (NULL);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback (NULL, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE, vendor_id,
                                               product_id,class_id, hotplug_callback_detach, NULL, &hp[1]);
        if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error registering callback 1\n");
            libusb_exit (NULL);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        while (done < 20) {
            //rc = libusb_handle_events (NULL);
            if (libusb_handle_events_completed(nullptr, nullptr) != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
                printf("libusb_handle_events() failed: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
        }

        if (handle) {
            libusb_close (handle);
        }

        libusb_exit (NULL);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<test> testClass1 = std::make_unique<test>();

    //just test
    for (;;)
    {
        //main service loop
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(2000000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libusb is a C library, it can only take non-member function pointers. The difference between a non-member function (or a `static` member function) pointer, and a pointer to a non-static member function is that a non-static member function needs an *object* to be called on, and C have no idea about C++ "objects".

With libusb you can solve it though, using `static` member function and the user-data pointer (which you pass a null-pointers now).

For example

```
class test
{
    // ...

    static int LIBUSB_CALL static_hotplug_callback_detach(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device *dev, libusb_hotplug_event event, void *user_data)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<test*>(user_data)->hotplug_callback_detach(ctx, dev, event);
    }

    int hotplug_callback_detach(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device *dev, libusb_hotplug_event event)
    {
        // Current code
    }

    // ...

    int okGo()
    {
        // ...

        rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback (NULL, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE, vendor_id,
                                           product_id,class_id, static_hotplug_callback_detach, this, &hp[1]);

        // ...
    }
```

Notice that the `static` member function is used when registering the callback, and that `this` is passed as the user data pointer.